# How to set System Variable for mySQL in RHEL 6.2?

Tags: linux, mysql

I am currently working on mySQL 5.6.10 server and RHEL 6.2. I need to set the system variable PATH for mySQL on RHEL 6.2 Terminal. How do I set it?

I also want to run a `.sql` file on Linux. I am using the following command:

```
mySQL DBname -uusername -ppassword <"path to the .sql file"
```

Please help me with the correct command to run the sql script file on Linux. If there are any prerequisites or configurations required to run the `.sql` file?

Comment: This appears to be a horrible XY Problem.  The question is supposedly about setting the PATH variable, but the real problem is apparently the capitalization of the `mysql` command.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you are asking.  First of all, the `mysql` command is all lowercase:

```
mysql DBname -uusername -ppassword <"path to the .sql file"
```

Also, the database name is case-sensitive, so make sure you have that correct as well.

To add a path to the `PATH` environment variable, use

```
export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/add
```

where `/path/to/add` is the path containing the binary you want to run.

But the path for the MySQL client executable should already be added.  If you got a `command not found` error, most likely it's because you used uppercase letters in the command name.